# How to compare two named ranges in same workbook but different worksheets?

Tags: excel, vba, loops, if-statement, foreach

I am trying to compare the values in one named range to another named range in another table on a different worksheet.

Scope of Names: Workbook Scoped

```
Current Roster = WSheet1
New Roster = WSheet2
CurrentNameList = Column F of CurrentRoster
NewNameList = Column F of New Roster
```

Issue: `Time out - Type Mismatch`

```
If c.Value = Range("NewNameList").Value Then
```

Here is where I am starting:

```vb
Sub Compare()
    For Each c In Range("CurrentNameList")
        If c.Value = Range("NewNameList").Value Then
           ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("CurrentRoster").Range("CurrentNameList").Offset(, 26).Value = "Active"
        Else
            ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Current Roster").Range("CurrentNameList").Offset(, 26).Value = "InActive"
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You should qualify the `Worksheet` each range is on.

Comment: Can you elaborate? I have given it ranges to effect but no worksheet to find on?

Comment: `Worksheets("yourworksheetname").Range("CurrentNameList")`. Best to qualify the `Workbook` before the worksheets too, perhaps `ThisWorkbook`.

Comment: You can't check for equality between a single cell and a multi-cell range: use `Match`  or `Find` for that.

Comment: @BigBen.  _You should qualify the Worksheet each range is on_ For Workbook scoped named ranges, no you shouldn't (provided the Workbook is active)

Comment: @PMNIServ1 please edit your Q to include the scope of the names,  and what they refer to

Comment: Scope included - @chrisneilsen

Comment: @PMNIServ1 you've now told us what the Names refer to, which is great.  Separate to that is the Name Scope.  Look at the name manager, you'll see they are scoped to either Workbook, or a specific Worksheet.  Since you accepted Tims' answer, I guess they are Workbook scoped

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your names are workbook-scoped you can refer to the ranges like this:

```vb
    Dim wb As Workbook, c As Range, m

    Set wb = ThisWorkbook 'always scope your ranges as explicitly as you can
    
    For Each c In wb.Names("CurrentNameList").RefersToRange.Cells
        'Use Match to check if a value in is a list
        m = Application.Match(c.Value, wb.Names("NewNameList").RefersToRange, 0) 'is the value in the list?
        'Did we get a match? If not then m is an error value
        c.Offset(0, 26).Value = IIf(IsError(m), "InActive", "Active")
    Next c
```